# Enable SMTP Port 587 instead of Port 25

Tags: exchange, smtp, email-server, microsoft-office-365

Through my Office365 subscription, I have an SMTP relay, ‘contoso-com.mail.outlook.com’. Currently this only accepts traffic on port 25

I want to look at setting up port 587 with TLS encryption, but keep port 25 running in junction with port 587 for the time being on the same SMTP relay.

My problem is that I'm not sure where my current physical mail server is (if it exists), I wasn't the one who originally set this up. Running nslookup only lists my Active Directory server

I currently have ‘contoso-com.mail.outlook.com’ listed under my domains as an MX record. As well as 'contoso.com' connector running with Microsoft Exchange admin center.

Mail flow settings for connector:

> Mail flow scenario
>
> From: Your organization's email server
>
> To: Office 365

Not much experience with SMTP relays so apologies for that

Comment: Agree with what vidarlo has replied above, 25 is REQUIRED for incoming/outgoing email. 587 can be ADDED for outgoing email from a client if you want (Receive connector)... however all email outbound will be transferred on port 25 to other mail servers. Above point is provided in the similar thread for your reference. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1851094-change-exchange-2013-smtp-port-from-25-to-587

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [smtp.office365.com on port 587 for outgoing e-mail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365).

What's listed as MX for your domain is for *receiving* e-mail. Microsoft supports StartTLS on port 25 for their Exchange 365 service. All other MTA's in the world will contact the MX at port 25, so there's no point in having port 587 enabled on a MX. That's only used for outgoing mail from client devices.

The fact that they support StartTLS can be verified with the command `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect hostname:25` which will output the certificate the host replied with.

Office365 is a hosted solution, where Microsoft runs your mail service. You don't pay for the server; you pay for sending and receiving e-mail as a service, and don't have to care about patching, upgrading or any configuration. That's simply handled by Microsoft. You have to take what you get; you can't modify Microsofts server environment, as it's shared with other customers.

Comment: Thanks vidarlo, makes a little more sense. Based from your link, I guess I already have 'Option 3' in place now. Will implementing Option 1 as well cause any issues to your knowledge?